# Vectorizing ndimage functions for my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I want to be able to vectorize this code:

```
def sobHypot(rec):
    a, b, c = rec.shape
    hype = np.ones((a,b,c))

    for i in xrange(c):
        x=ndimage.sobel(abs(rec[...,i])**2,axis=0, mode='constant')
        y=ndimage.sobel(abs(rec[...,i])**2,axis=1, mode='constant')
        hype[...,i] = np.hypot(x,y)
        hype[...,i] = hype[...,i].mean()

    index = hype.argmax()
    return index
```

where rec,shape returns (1024,1024,20)

Comment: What do you mean by vectorize?

Comment: As in, get rid of the for loop

Comment: Even as is (without vectorization), don't take the `abs` and then square it ... squaring without `abs` should do the same thing.  Also, just square it once and save the squared matrix.  This only saves about 20% of the time, so of course true vectorization would be better :P

Comment: I took the advice of doing the squaring before I put it in the loop, but because I have complex values in this matrix, I have to do abs before I square it. Mathematically, it makes no sense, but testing it in python, if I don't take the abs then square it, the complex values stay in.

Ex:
    (2+2j)**2 #prints 8j
    abs(2+2j)**2 #prints 8

Comment: I can, however, just take the abs of it, and not square it. Answer is still the same for the index. Basically just a scaling factor in the image.

Comment: @NightHallow Are you forgetting the fact the a complex number squared is **not** necessarily a real number. It is true however that a complex number times its _complex conjugate_ is real...

Comment: Ah, yes, because `(2+2j)**2` is `(2+2j) * (2+2j)`, and only the cross-term survives. You want `(2+2j) * (2-2j)`, the standard 'math' interpretation of `c**2 = c * c.conj()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can avoid the for-loop with the sobel filter:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import sobel

def sobHypot_vec(rec):
    r = np.abs(rec)
    x = sobel(r, 0, mode='constant')
    y = sobel(r, 1, mode='constant')
    h = np.hypot(x, y)
    h = np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, h, [0,1])
    return h.argmax()
```

I'm not sure if the sobel filter is particularly necessary in your application, and this is hard to test without your particular 20-layer 'image', but you could try using `np.gradient` instead of running the sobel twice.  The advantage is that `gradient` runs in three dimensions. You can ignore the component in the third, and take the hypot of just the first two.  This seems wasteful but is actually still faster in my tests.

For a variety of randomly generated images, `r = np.random.rand(1024,1024,20) + np.random.rand(1024,1024,20)*1j`, this gives the same answer as your code, but test it to be sure, and possibly fiddle with the `dx, dy` arguments of [`np.gradient`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

```
def grad_max(rec):
    g = np.gradient(np.abs(rec))[:2]  # ignore derivative in third dimension
    h = np.hypot(*g)
    h = np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, h, [0,1]) # mean along first and second dimension 
    return h.argmax()
```

Using this code for timing:

```
def sobHypot_clean(rec):
    rs = rec.shape
    hype = np.ones(rs)
    r = np.abs(rec)
    for i in xrange(rs[-1]):
        ri = r[...,i]
        x = sobel(ri, 0, mode='constant')
        y = sobel(ri, 1, mode='constant')
        hype[...,i] = np.hypot(x,y).mean()
    return hype.argmax()
```

Timing:

```
In [1]: r = np.random.rand(1024,1024,20) + np.random.rand(1024,1024,20)*1j

# Original Post
In [2]: timeit sobHypot(r)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.85 s per loop

#cleaned up a bit:
In [3]: timeit sobHypot_clean(r)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.64 s per loop

# vectorized:
In [4]: timeit sobHypot_vec(r)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.98 s per loop

# using np.gradient:
In [5]: timeit grad_max(r)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.12 s per loop
```

Please test any of these functions on your own images to be sure they give the desired output, since different types of arrays could react differently from the simple random tests I did.

Comment: So, testing with my images, these functions can all give me different values for the same image. My image is a reconstruction of a hologram. What I am trying to do with this function is basically find where an image is in focus, i.e the sharpest. I am even going about this the right way? And so far, the original function gets the closest to what I would pick everytime.

Comment: I'm not surprised, these sorts of methods are pretty sensitive to small differences in the method and the input, though it seems weird that `sobHypot_clean` is different from your original `sobHypot`.  The first function, `sobHypot_vec` is the most direct answer to your question and should give theoretically the same result, unless I'm missing something.  You could try putting the `**2` back in and see if that actually helps.  `grad_max` is clearly different but is simpler and will run faster.